# Is it possible to use GWTP on GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt-platform

I would like to use GWTP (GTP-Platform) on the GAE, but I have not seen any concrete example.
Is there any project to download ?

Tks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Yes you can! Gwt-Platform is build on Gwt and our goal is to always
>   have an easy to use with GAE framework.
>
> As for examples, here's some: http://code.google.com/p/puzzlebazar/
>   http://code.google.com/p/homequest/
>   http://code.google.com/p/arcbees-hive/

Comment: ok, they should EXPLICITLY say it in their google project introduction. But thanks !